# How to run ctest after building my project with cmake

Tags: cmake, ctest

I want my tests to be launched each time my project is successfully built. And if some tests are broken I want my build to be broken too. By default I need to run tests manually by running `ctest` command. CTest can actually build project but I use IDE that invokes `make` to build sources. And `make` doesn't run tests.

I add this command to my root CMakeLists.txt file but it doesn't work.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT tests.txt 
                   POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ctest --output-on-failure)
```

CMake doesn't return any errors and everything builds fine but my custom command doesn't invokes. How can I run something after each successful build in CMake?

**Update:**

My final solution is creating this macro:

```
macro(add_unit_test target target_test)
    set(UNIT_TEST_TARGETS ${UNIT_TEST_TARGETS} ${target_test} PARENT_SCOPE)
    add_test(target ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${target_test})
endmacro(add_unit_test)
```

It calls `add_test` and remembers test target in a list. Every test in a project added by this macro. In the root CMakeLists.txt I have this code:

```
add_custom_target( all_tests ALL
                   DEPENDS ${UNIT_TEST_TARGETS}
)
add_custom_command(TARGET all_tests
                   COMMENT "Run tests"
                   POST_BUILD COMMAND ctest ARGS --output-on-failure
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

It creates custom target that depends on all unit tests in a project. Custom command is runs  after `all_tests` target was built.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - in your macro, in `add_test`, I think you need `${target_test}` instead of `target_test`

Comment: What did you mean in your comment on the answer, regarding your "Update" section here, regarding avoiding running "stale tests"?  At first, I thought you came up with a way to only run tests that were newly built.  But, I now see this runs `ctest` on all tests.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This form of [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command) will only execute if another CMake target has a dependency on "tests.txt".  I assume that no other target has "tests.txt" as an input file, hence the custom command never runs.

I think you could use the second form of `add_custom_command` to achieve your goal; something like:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET MainTest
                   POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ctest -C $<CONFIGURATION> --output-on-failure)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, appreciate this! I found similar solution. I create custom target that depends on every unit test in the project and than I use `add_custom_command` with my custom target as a TARGET parameter. This is essential because I don't want to run stale tests. And I also discover that it is impossible to enumerate all the targets in the `cmake` project so list of targets need to be maintained manually.

Comment: I have a question regarding running test. Currently I have an `sh`-script building the project in a separate build directory. Is it common to add `ctest` invokation in the script after `cmake . && make` is done?

Comment: A bit buggy example.  $<CONFIGURATION> may be not set.  In this case `--output-on-failure` will become an argument for `-C`.