# Global custom target in CMake

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, target

I wanted to write a little Unit-test system with CMake that I can easily copy and paste in all my projects so I came up with this:

```
include(CMakeParseArguments)
set(UNIT_TEST "unit_tests")
add_custom_target(${UNIT_TEST} ALL VERBATIM)

function(add_unit_test dependency)
    cmake_parse_arguments(UT_ "" "NAME" "" ${ARGN})
    if(NOT ${UT_NAME})
        set(${UT_NAME} ${ARG0})
    endif()

    add_test(${ARGN})
    add_dependencies(${UNIT_TEST} ${dependency})
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${UNIT_TEST}
                   COMMENT "Run tests"
                   POST_BUILD COMMAND ctest
                   ARGS -R ${UT_NAME} --output-on-failures
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
                   VERBATIM)
endfunction(add_unit_test)
```

I hoped that it would work fine like that and run all unit tests I would add in my project by calling `add_unit_test(dep ...)` with a dependency to compile before and then the same arguments as for `add_test(...)`. In reality this error shows up:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/testing.cmake:13 (add_custom_command):
  Policy CMP0040 is not set: The target in the TARGET signature of
  add_custom_command() must exist.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0040" for
  policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and
  suppress this warning.

  The target name "unit_tests" is unknown in this context.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  source/test/CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_unit_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Why exactly is the target unknown at this point? `include(cmake/testing.cmake)` is the first thing I call after `cmake_minimum_required` in my project build script, so it can't be because `add_custom_target(${UNIT_TEST} ALL VERBATIM)` hasn't been called yet.

Is there a way I can add a custom command to the UNIT_TEST target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just came across your question and tried to reproduce your problem.

My first recommendation would be: if you call `enable_testing()` you directly get a "Run Tests" target generated by CMake. See [CMake: Testing with CTest](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest#Simple_Testing):

> Once you have built the project, you can execute all tests via
>
> ```
> make test
> ```
>
> with Makefile generators, or by rebuilding the RUN_TESTS target in
>   your IDE. Internally this runs CTest to actually perform the testing;
>   you could just as well execute
>
> ```
> ctest
> ```
>
> in the binary directory of your build.

**Debugging your given Code**

If I name a valid target as the first parameter of your `add_unit_test()` I don't get the `CMP0040` error. So just check again that you give a valid target.

But your script has some errors in it. Here is a working version:

```
include(CMakeParseArguments)

enable_testing()

set(UNIT_TEST "unit_tests")
add_custom_target(${UNIT_TEST} ALL)

function(add_unit_test dependency)
    cmake_parse_arguments(UT "" "NAME" "COMMAND" ${ARGN} )
    if("${UT_NAME}" STREQUAL "")
        set(${UT_NAME} "${ARGV1}")
    endif()
    add_test(${ARGN})
    add_dependencies(${UNIT_TEST} ${dependency})
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${UNIT_TEST}
                   COMMENT "Run tests"
                   POST_BUILD COMMAND ctest
                   ARGS -C $<CONFIGURATION> -R "^${UT_NAME}$" --output-on-failures)
endfunction(add_unit_test)
```

- Added `enable_testing()`
- Removed the trailing `_` of `UT` in `cmake_parse_arguments(UT ...)`
- Compare for empty string with `STREQUAL ""`
- Added a `V` to `ARGV1` and going for the second parameter (index 0 is `dependency`)
- Removed not needed `VERBATIM`
- Added needed `-C $<CONFIGURATION>` parameter (see [How to run ctest after building my project with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115075/how-to-run-ctest-after-building-my-project-with-cmake))
- Changed the RegEx to `"^${UT_NAME}$"` for exact name matching

Moving the above code into a file called `UnitTest.cmake` I have successfully tested with the following main `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Example CXX)

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/UnitTest.cmake)

file(WRITE foo.cc "#include <windows.h>\nint main() {\nreturn 0;\n}")

add_executable(MyTest foo.cc)
add_unit_test(MyTest NAME SomeTest COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:MyTest>)

add_executable(MyTest2 foo.cc)
add_unit_test(MyTest2 NAME SomeTest2 COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:MyTest2>)
```