# How do I add the -j option to my ctest cmake file?

Tags: cmake, ctest

I would like to run parallel jobs when running `ctest`.  I tried setting

```
set(CTEST_PARALLEL_LEVEL 8)
```

in

```
CTestCustom.cmake.in
```

but this didn't change the command line options after I re-generated my build files.

I am on windows, using visual studio.

Comment: `CTEST_PARALLEL_LEVEL` should be provided as an environment variable (see [cmCTest.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmCTest.cxx#L2535)). Have you tried `set(ENV{CTEST_PARALLEL_LEVEL} 8)`?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it didn't seem to help.  Where should I set this in my files?  In VIsualStudio, RUN_TESTS creates a post-build step that runs the ctest exe.  I am hoping to add a line in my cmake files that adds a `-j 8` command line parameter to this post-build step

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't change the command line that is used when you build `RUN_TESTS` on Visual Studio. There are no options in the code (see [`cmGlobalGenerator::CreateDefaultGlobalTargets()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmGlobalGenerator.cxx#L2396)).

I see the following possible approaches:

1. Set the `CTEST_PARALLEL_LEVEL` environment variable globally in your Windows (so it's just part of you machines CMake/CTest configuration) or add a start script for your Visual Studio.

   - [Can I set an environment variable for an application using a shortcut in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036325/can-i-set-an-environment-variable-for-an-application-using-a-shortcut-in-windows)
2. Create your own target with something like

   ```
   add_custom_target(
       RUN_TESTS_J8 
           COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -j 8 -C $<CONFIGURATION> --force-new-ctest-process 
           WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
   )
   ```

   - [CMake: setting an environmental variable for ctest (or otherwise getting failed test output from ctest/make test automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158091/cmake-setting-an-environmental-variable-for-ctest-or-otherwise-getting-failed)

   And mayby group it together with the other predefined targets

   ```
   set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
   set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY PREDEFINED_TARGETS_FOLDER "CMake")
   set_property(TARGET RUN_TESTS_J8 PROPERTY FOLDER "CMake")
   ```
3. Combining build & run as a `POST_BUILD` step for the tests itself

   ```
   add_custom_command(
       TARGET MyTest
       POST_BUILD
          COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -C $<CONFIGURATION> -R "^MyTest$" --output-on-failures
          WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
   )
   ```

   Then it would be - as being part of the normal build - by itself executed in parallel.

   - [Global custom target in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456950/global-custom-target-in-cmake)
   - [How to run ctest after building my project with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115075/how-to-run-ctest-after-building-my-project-with-cmake)

**More References**

- [Using cmake how do I get verbose output from ctest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709914/using-cmake-how-do-i-get-verbose-output-from-ctest)

Comment: Wow, thanks for all of this information. I decided on the simplest approach from your suggestions - set a windows env variable. This works great.