# How to do code coverage in cmake

Tags: cmake, ctest

I want to use code coverage tools(lcov) in my cmake project.
I read the example here https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake
The tests are added in my project using the 'add_test()' cmake function.

I want to create a custom target, something called 'test_coverage', that when invoked for execution should run all the tests, collect their coverage data and generate the html(using genhtml) in a directory 'code_coverage'.

Is there a way I could get the list of all the tests in my project and their directory paths, so that in the custom target 'test_coverage' I could execute each test individually and collect its coverage data ?

Comment: From your decription I assume you have already read [Detailed guide on using gcov with CMake/CDash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116488/detailed-guide-on-using-gcov-with-cmake-cdash). But did you see e.g. https://github.com/stepcode/stepcode/blob/master/lcov.cmake ? `CTest` knows/can extract the list of test in your CMake's binary output directory and with its script mode `ctest -S ...` you can automate the whole build, test and collect coverage data process.

Comment: Also useful could be [How to run ctest after building my project with cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115075/how-to-run-ctest-after-building-my-project-with-cmake)

Comment: @Florian I don't see a ctest_coverage call in the lcov.cmake example? Also, are you saying you can perform the coverage analysis without a script (-S) at all? Can you point to an example of how to do that? I'm interested in coverage analysis of all of the test targets in aggregate.

Comment: Maybe this module which we are using is useful for you: https://code.cor-lab.de/projects/rsc/repository/entry/cmake/Modules/EnableCoverageReport.cmake. It uses lcov and gcovr  to generate the reports. It still doesn't help to automatically collect the test targets, but maybe it saves some time to write your coverage logic.

Comment: This is now answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116488/detailed-guide-on-using-gcov-with-cmake-cdash/16536401#16536401

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detailed guide on using gcov with CMake/CDash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116488/detailed-guide-on-using-gcov-with-cmake-cdash)