# CMake: "Linked Library" error (0xc0000135) when attempting to run on Jenkins Build Machine

Tags: c++, jenkins, visual-studio-2015, cmake, googletest

CMake relative newbie.

I currently have a Cross-compiling (Windows 10/CentOS) project where I have added a post-build hook to automatically run Google Test, using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115075/how-to-run-ctest-after-building-my-project-with-cmake).

Everything works great in Windows and Linux, it correctly builds then executes the Google Test Executable. However, on our Window's server Jenkin's build system, I keep getting the following:

```
CMake Error at <path to cmake>/cmake-3.17/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:40 (message):
    Error running test executable.

      Path: '<path to project root>/build/extern/<submodule>/tests/Debug/<project>.test.exe'
      Result: Exit code 0xc0000135
```

Doing research, the error code seems to be related to the exe missing a dynamically linked library. However, I can't figure out if it is the main project library (call it project.lib) is missing, or something else. Any help/experience on debugging this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an answer:

- It turned out the dll libraries for Windows .Net was *not* installed. After installing them/making sure they were on the path, the problem resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `Catch2` on an integration machine using Azure DevOps.

The integration report displays:

```
CMake Error at C:/Projets/<PROJECT>/application/testing/Catch2/extras/CatchAddTests.cmake:45 (message):
  Error running test executable
  'C:/Projets/<PROJECT>/application/build/testing/Process/Debug/testing_Process.exe':


    Result: Exit code 0xc0000135



    Output:
```

The root cause: the `testing_Process.exe` binary is missing a required `.dll` library of external SDK.

The solution: Add the `.dll` required to the system path of the integration machine.